# Amazon Athena - how to count the distinct value?

Tags: count, aggregation, amazon-athena

I am trying to count the distinct value after group by two other columns.

In Oracle, this query will look like this:

```
SELECT column_1,
       column_2,
       column_3, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT (column_1) OVER(PARTITION by column_2, column_3) as "count_distinct"
FROM table;
```

In Athena, similarly, I did

```
SELECT column_1,
       column_2,
       column_3, 
       APPROX_DISTINCT(column_1) OVER(PARTITION by column_2, column_3) as "count_distinct"
FROM table;
```

However, I am not sure if `approx_distinct` is the same thing as `count(distinct)` because it is an approximation if I understood correctly.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're like to get for that sample

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that [`approx_distinct`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#approx_distinct) is an approximate aggregation function. It has small standard error, so it is often very useful & more efficient than `count(DISTINCT x)` would be.

Your original syntax does not work yet in Presto, which Athena is based on. See https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/5523